# Dynamic date in WHERE clause dependent on current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to make a Date in a `WHERE` clause dynamic so that if the current date (`GETDATE()` ?) is **less than** July 1st (7/1) of the current year (of when `GETDATE()` is run) then make the date in the `WHERE` clause be 7/1 of the **previous** year. If the current date is **greater than** 7/1 of the current year then make the date in the `WHERE` clause be 7/1 of the **current** year. Here are a few examples.

```
   --EXAMPLE 1:
        GETDATE() = 4/17/19

        SELECT A.DATE
        FROM TEST_TABLE A
        WHERE A.DATE >'2018-07-01'  <-- This would be dynamic based on the current date being less than 7/1 of this year, so use previous year.

   --EXAMPLE 2:

       GETDATE() = 7/2/19

       SELECT A.DATE
       FROM TEST_TABLE A
       WHERE A.DATE > '2019-07-01' <-- 2019 Because current date is greater than 7/1 of current year we use the current year.
```

I will be using this in a view, so I don't believe I can declare and use variables so I'm looking for other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of doing it without a case/else statement:

`CONCAT(Year(DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())), '/07/01')`

This subtracts 6 months from the current date (`DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())`), takes only the year of that new date (`Year(...)`) and appends `/07/01` to the end (`CONCAT(..., '/07/01')`).

**Examples:**

`SELECT CONCAT(Year(DATEADD(month, -6, '2017/06/30')), '/07/01');`
outputs
`2016/07/01`

and

`SELECT CONCAT(Year(DATEADD(month, -6, '2017/07/01')), '/07/01');` outputs `2017/07/01`

**Used in context:**

```
SELECT A.DATE
       FROM TEST_TABLE A
       WHERE A.DATE > CONCAT(Year(DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())), '/07/01');
```

Comment: So this will dynamically value the Year into the string? So hypothetically if GETDATE() returns '2019-04-17' (which is less than 7/1 of this year) then it will return the Year 2018 ?  If GETDATE() returned a current date of '2019-07-02' then it would return the year 2019 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Try it yourself!